# android identify tablerow

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

So, is there any easy way to identify the tablerow clicked?
I have a tablelayout with static data, like a menu. When the user click any tablerow I want to start the specified activity. 
I've googled a couple of hours but everyone seem to use the view inside the tablerows text property to identify it, which sucks if you translate the app. I tried to find some getIndex property of the TableLayouit but no luck, and the views .getId property is useless.

I guess the solution is to have specific onclicklisteners on each tablerow but that will generate a lot of (unnecessary) code and there must be a better solution?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*if you make your activity as an extension of `ListView()` and you put your options in a list you can actually override the method 
    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        }
and the position attribute of that method is an int which indicates what row you actually click
this is a solution that i am sure actually works, so if your table layout is not too complicated i suggest you to make a list and override this method!*

ok, I'll try another one since that one causes you other problems, you could make something like this:

in the `onCreate()`:

```
firstTextVIew = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstText);

 firstTextView.setOnClickListener(this);

secondTextVIew = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondText);

 secondTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

after the `onCreate()`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {       

    /*make a list of cases for any text view, where __TextView is the name you gave to the textview when you made the getViewById() on the start of the activity*/
        if(v == firstTextView){         
            //start activity
        }
    if(v == secondTextView){        
            //start activity
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks. I just changed from ListView to TableLayout because I had other problems with the ListView, like getting my background drawable look good and prevent the Listview from filling the whole screen :S

Comment: getId() gave me weird numbers, like "212221" . .not the id's I set in my xml.. if not the onClick got caught by the textView inside instead of the tablerow? ..hmmm

Comment: i edited my answer, try this new one, I'm pretty sure it works!

Comment: Nopes, tried to LOG it, getId() is just numbers not the android:id="@+id/row_contact_support" I put in my xml

Comment: because Android gives a complex id to any new view you create from the xml, just try the code i gave you, it works! trust me

Comment: Thanks again, I can't get it to work :S
I tried to catch both the tablerow and the textview inside it, but I always fall down into thew "else" .. I wonder which view actually recieves the onclick.. the TableLayout itself? You got me down the right track however, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I am pretty sure that the one that receives the onClick is the actual view, so it should be the textView.. it's strange it does not work, check if you chose the same ids from the xml when you do getViewById()

Comment: You were right to be sure, it was me mismatching the code, thanks a lot for the help